# Constant difference between producer and consumer Kafka stream metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, grafana, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

Using Kafka stream metrics: `sum(irate(kafka_producer_producer_metrics_record_send_total{}[1m]))` and `sum(irate(kafka_consumer_consumer_fetch_manager_metrics_records_consumed_total{}[1m]))` I have noticed that for every Kafka stream app - consumer rate is always twice higher than producer rate. What is reason of this behavior?
[image]

If this is always higher I would suppose that there should be some kind of buffer and sometimes producer rate should be higher than consumer rate but it is not and memory doesn't explode.

Other info:
Topic has 1 partition with replication 2.
Kafka stream app from image is simple map.

```
│   Kafka:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
│     Config:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
│       default.replication.factor:                3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
│       inter.broker.protocol.version:             3.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
│       min.insync.replicas:                       2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
│       offsets.topic.replication.factor:          3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
│       transaction.state.log.min.isr:             2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
│       transaction.state.log.replication.factor:  3
```

Kafka streams config:

```
    props.put(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 1);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, 2);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, earliest);
```

Comment: Can you share your streams config? What's num.standby.replicas ?

Comment: I have added it to question body. Config  `num.standby.replicas` is default.

Comment: Well, I guess it depends what your application is doing... A single input record can result in zero, one, or multiple produces messages depending or your program. For example if you filter messages, your output would be smaller. If you join to streams, your output is most likely larger. Also, if state is involved, there are additional write to changelog topics...

Comment: Yes, but this application (from chart) is simple map, which is mapping string to uppercase string. I have created this simple Kafka Stream app because I have found this described previously behavior in my data processing stream where filters, states, etc. are implemented. It turned out that this behavior applies to both.